# Get the name of the uploaded file

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS1 and Js. Here i am uploading a file which will be saved on my drive as well as in mongodb. What I am trying to do is to get the uploaded file name which can easily be seen here in attached picture. Kindly help me out with this.

[image: Name of the uploaded file is highlighted]

```
 $scope.uploadedFileList.push(p);
        $('#addproFile').ajaxfileupload({
          action: 'http://' + window.location.hostname + ':' + window.location.port + '/api/upload',
          valid_extensions : ['md','csv','css', 'txt'],
          params: {
            dummy_name: p
          },
          onComplete: function(response) {
            console.log('custom handler for file:');
            alert(JSON.stringify(response));
             /* $scope.nameString = uploadedFileList.join(',');
              $scope.$apply();*/
          },

          onCancel: function() {
            console.log('no file selected');
          }
        });
```

**This is my controller**

```
(function($) {
$.fn.ajaxfileupload = function(options) {
    var settings = {
      params: {},
      action: '',
      onStart: function() { },
      onComplete: function(response) { },
      onCancel: function() { },
      validate_extensions : true,
      valid_extensions : ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg'],
      submit_button : null
    };

    var uploading_file = false;

    if ( options ) { 
      $.extend( settings, options );
    }


    // 'this' is a jQuery collection of one or more (hopefully) 
    //  file elements, but doesn't check for this yet
    return this.each(function() {
      var $element = $(this);

      // Skip elements that are already setup. May replace this 
      //  with uninit() later, to allow updating that settings
      if($element.data('ajaxUploader-setup') === true) return;

      $element.change(function()
      {
        // since a new image was selected, reset the marker
        uploading_file = false;

        // only update the file from here if we haven't assigned a submit button
        if (settings.submit_button == null)
        {
          upload_file();
        }
      });

      if (settings.submit_button == null)
      {
        // do nothing
      } else
      {
        settings.submit_button.click(function(e)
        {
          // Prevent non-AJAXy submit
          e.preventDefault();

          // only attempt to upload file if we're not uploading
          if (!uploading_file)
          {
            upload_file();
          }
        });
      }

      var upload_file = function()
      {
        if($element.val() == '') return settings.onCancel.apply($element, [settings.params]);

        // make sure extension is valid
        var ext = $element.val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
        if(true == settings.validate_extensions && $.inArray(ext, settings.valid_extensions) == -1)
        {
          // Pass back to the user
          settings.onComplete.apply($element, [{status: false, message: 'The select file type is invalid. File must be ' + settings.valid_extensions.join(', ') + '.'}, settings.params]);
        } else
        { 
          uploading_file = true;

          // Creates the form, extra inputs and iframe used to 
          //  submit / upload the file
          wrapElement($element);

          // Call user-supplied (or default) onStart(), setting
          //  it's this context to the file DOM element
          var ret = settings.onStart.apply($element, [settings.params]);

          // let onStart have the option to cancel the upload
          if(ret !== false)
          {
            $element.parent('form').submit(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); }).submit();
          } else {
            uploading_file = false;
          }
        }
      };

      // Mark this element as setup
      $element.data('ajaxUploader-setup', true);

      /*
      // Internal handler that tries to parse the response 
      //  and clean up after ourselves. 
      */
      var handleResponse = function(loadedFrame, element) {
        var response, responseStr = $(loadedFrame).contents().text();
        try {
          //response = $.parseJSON($.trim(responseStr));
          response = JSON.parse(responseStr);
        } catch(e) {
          response = responseStr;
        }

        // Tear-down the wrapper form
        element.siblings().remove();
        element.unwrap();

        uploading_file = false;

        // Pass back to the user
        settings.onComplete.apply(element, [response, settings.params]);
      };

      /*
      // Wraps element in a <form> tag, and inserts hidden inputs for each
      //  key:value pair in settings.params so they can be sent along with
      //  the upload. Then, creates an iframe that the whole thing is 
      //  uploaded through. 
      */
      var wrapElement = function(element) {
        // Create an iframe to submit through, using a semi-unique ID
        var frame_id = 'ajaxUploader-iframe-' + Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000)
        $('body').after('<iframe width="0" height="0" style="display:none;" name="'+frame_id+'" id="'+frame_id+'"/>');
        $('#'+frame_id).get(0).onload = function() {
          handleResponse(this, element);
        };

        // Wrap it in a form
        element.wrap(function() {
          return '<form action="' + settings.action + '" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="'+frame_id+'" />'
        })
        // Insert <input type='hidden'>'s for each param
        .before(function() {
          var key, html = '';
          for(key in settings.params) {
            var paramVal = settings.params[key];
            if (typeof paramVal === 'function') {
              paramVal = paramVal();
            }
            html += '<input type="hidden" name="' + key + '" value="' + paramVal + '" />';
          }
          return html;
        });
      }
    });
  }
})( jQuery )
```

this is my ajax file upload function

Comment: `FileList[0]['name']`?

Comment: sorry can u be more detailed ?

Comment: you can access it by using FileList[0]['name']. in the above image FileList object has name in 0th index

Comment: @guradio - you didn't write out the exact code for the OP :p lol, @ more detailed.

Comment: @guradio this comment is answer of the question

Comment: @shv22 yes it is @ Jaromanda X lol :)